# RemoteViewsFactory called getViewAt when empty dataset

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview, stackview

I'm working on widget for my application which based on StackView and should display some items. Count of items can vary due to user actions - lets say it is some kind of favorites menu. I have implemented RemoteViewsFactory descendant to generate views for StackView:

```
public class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    private List<Item> data;
    private Context context;

    public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        data = new DAO(context).getFavouriteCards();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        data = new DAO(context).getWidgetItems(); // refresh widget dataset
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        Item item = data.get(position);
        // this is my problem and will be explained below - 
        // here I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException, position = 0

            ...
    }
    // I have omitted other methods to avoid verbosity
}
```

All works well at first widget start - widget successfully displays empty view and all goes well. After I added some new element to favourites I notify AppWidgetManager immediately:

```
AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getActivity());
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getActivity(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(component);
widgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(widgetIds, R.id.widgets_stack);
```

All is well at this point - dataset successfully changed and I see my favorite item on widget. But when I remove my single element from favorites and favorites become empty (AppWidgetManager notified of course) I receive IndexOutOfBoundsException in my getViewAtMethod:

```
10-15 17:26:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(30964): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

First of all I've checked what `getCount()` returns after `onDataSetChanged()` fires - it was 0. So I don't understand why `RemoteViewsFactory` calls `getViewAt()` when `getCount()` returns 0. As far as I understanding, `RemoteViewFactory` is like a usual adapter so this behavior is completely confusing me. So maybe my suggestions about it are incorrect and I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**
Today I've changed my widget layout to use `ListView` instead of `StackView` while trying to fix some gui bug. And all works well at now. Further experiment shows that `AdapterViewFlipper` have same issue as StackView. As far as I understood there are some aspects working with `AdapterViewAnimator` descendants - can anyone confirm/refute my assumption?

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but I happen to run on the same issue. The data set is updated, but somehow the RemoteViewsFactory uses an old value of "getCount". Did you find something else out?

Comment: @mdelolmo Unfortunately I didn't find solution for this issue and reworked my widget to display single item and navigate through items using < and > buttons.

Comment: The answer below solved this issue for me. It's a workaround but, a nice one :)

Comment: @BojanIlievski I don't mind to accept khose's answer and his solution really should work, but, generally my question was about explanation of source of this bug and behavior of AdapterViewAnimator.

Answer (score 13):

Same problem here. Since the solution is not yet coming (Android 4.4 here and it still happens), I think the best solution for now is basically a workaround to avoid the crash. Some devs will call it "hack"...

For now:

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    if (position >= getCount())
            return getLoadingView();
    }
    //.... Rest of your normal configuration
}
```

Make sure you return a view properly on `getLoadingView()`

Comment: This worked for me. It doesnt crash anymore (so far), and it seems to skip right over this case and show the "empty" widget view, which is what I wanted anyway. Though, I wonder if this is an issue with just StackViews?